With what tense I follow up "it's time"
When we use the structure "it's time" even if we refer to the future we rather use past tenses for example "it high time we took a shower" we mean now not in the past.
My question is what if I follow this structure with more than one clause. Do I stick to the past tenses or follow up with present ones? Let me provide examples to make my question more clear.

Now, it's time we took a shower because we are or were sweaty

Now, it's time you did it before he comes or came



Note, you can also just use an infinitive. "It's time to do it."

We use past tense after it’s time or it’s high time not because the action to take is in the past but because they are due or overdue.  Hence this shouldn’t cause the subordinate clause to go past tense; we use the present tense:

Now, it's time we took a shower because we are sweaty.
Now, it's time you did it before he comes.


Could I use past perfect in my 2 example and say "Now, it's time you had done it before he comes"?

@Adam: Whether it's technically grammatical or not, it feels quite...contorted, and definitely isn't common.  I wouldn't use it, and i'd suspect the speaker who did of being a bit confused.
